# Can I reference an MSDeploy parameter value in a manifest file?

Tags: msdeploy, webdeploy

In the MSDeploy parameter file, I can reference parameter values with curly braces like this:

```
<parameter name="ServiceUri" defaultValue="http://{ServiceHost}/bleh">
```

Using parameters in the manifest in the same way doesn't seem to work.  Is there any way to reference parameter values in the manifest?